# How can I let foreach loop to check user authentication process?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a wordpress plugin, I need to let users register without warning them that some "passwords" are not allowed. 
In my foreach loop, I need to check 1 password if it was used, if it was not, I will authenticate the user.

This is my current code, first loop, it will check user credentials, if they were incorrect, it will show erorr message, if correct, it will direct him to his CP:

```
    if (isset($_POST["username"])) {

    $creds = array();
    $creds['user_login'] = $_POST["username"];
    $creds['user_password'] = $user_pass;
    if (isset($_POST["remember"]))
        $creds['remember'] = true;

    else
    {

         $user = wp_signon($creds, false);
        if (is_wp_error($user))
            echo $user->get_error_message();
        else
            wp_redirect(admin_url());


    }     
}
```

But what I need is that to check user credentials first if they were correct, I need to direct him to his CP, if not correct, I need to pass the current loop to next check,because I need to add my if statement to check user in each loop if he was using a certain words of passwords like "passw0rd".
any advise?

Comment: What loop?  It's not clear to me what you're trying to describe.  This code doesn't make much sense to me.  If `isset($_POST["remember"])` is false, why do you immediately check that same thing again in the `else` block?  It's still going to be false.

Comment: sorry for that, I did remove it. I didn't show the loop because my issue is with this part of code only. I need to check user cred's if they were correct first, if not, I need to pass to next loop.

Comment: Are you just looking for the `wp_check_password()` function?  https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_check_password

Comment: No, actually $user = wp_signon($creds, false) is fine with me, but I need to direct user to his CP first, if not correct cred's, I need to move forward.

Answer (score 0):

```
   $user = wp_signon($creds, false);
    if (is_wp_error($user))
        echo $user->get_error_message();
    else
        wp_redirect(admin_url());
```

This is the part of the code which you should be interested in utalizing. As you state in your question, you want to do something after the user has failed to login.

If you edit that to something like:

```
 function nextCheck($userData){
   echo $userData['user_login'].' '.$userData['user_password'];
 }

 $user = wp_signon($creds, false);
    if (is_wp_error($user)){
        nextCheck($creds);
        echo $user->get_error_message();
     }
    else
        wp_redirect(admin_url());
```

You'll be able to carry on with what ever your next task is.

Comment: thank you my friend, I need `wp_redirect(admin_url());` first if user cred's were correct, then I need to move forward if cred's are incorrect. my code and yours are putting user redirecting last step!

Comment: This line `if (is_wp_error($user))` is the line which checks the users signin details. If that is true (that the user failed to login) it executes the code within the brackets. If the creds are incorrect, it will always be within that block that you can find out.